# is it possible to change data type of column when the column already has data in it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, alter-table

such as for column (xx) where the data type is varchar and has values in it such as 'cons', 'alts' to convert it to int...
if it is not possible to do so what other options do we have

Comment: Nope `cons, alts` cannot be converted to `INT`. Possible Only if **implicit conversion** of existing data to `INT` is possible

Comment: IF you have a predefined correspondence,that is, cons=1 alts=2 etc., it might be possible if you dont have that many values

Comment: If you can't do implicit conversion, you could always use update statements to alter the data to a value that will allow it - such as cons = 1, ALTs = 2 etc

Answer (score 0):

After updating the value.  Something like this:

```
update t
    set column = NULL
    where column not like '%[^0-9]%' or column not like '-[^0-9]%';

alter t alter column int;
```

Once the values are valid, you should be able to modify the type, assuming a bunch of other conditions on the column (involving the use in constraints and so on).

EDIT:

If you want to create a reference table, normally you would add a new column.  This is nasty, because the columns get re-ordered.  So, you could use this hack:

```
create table columnRef (
    columnRefId int not null identity primarykey,
    value varchar(255) unique
);

insert into columnRef(value)
    select distinct column from t;

alter table t add newvalue varchar(255);

update t newvalue = column;

update t
    column = cast(columnRefId as varchar(255))
    from t join
         columnRef cr
         on t.newvalue = cr.value;

alter t modify column int;

alter t drop newvalue;
```

After writing this, I realized that you don't need `newvalue`.  However, somehow I'm uncomfortable modifying the data in the column used for the `join` and not being able to check the accuracy afterwards.